# Amazon cloudsearch describedoamin usage

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use describeDomains function of AWS CloudSearch. But I am getting the below error.

> exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Method Aws\CloudSearch  \CloudSearchClient::describeDomains() does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already figured this out by now, but I think you just need to fix the casing of the `DescribeDomains()` method (note the initial capital D).

See PHP SDK documentation: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cloudsearch-2013-01-01.html#describedomains